# How to manipulate Array's Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

Given an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance of marathon participants with their respective finish times. How do I determine positions (i.e first, second, third) of any two or more participants that finished at exactly same time?  For example:

> @runners = Runners.where(maranthon_year_id: 2016, location: 'ask').order(finish_time: :asc)

Normally, I'd iterate through this in view like this:

```
  <% count = 0 %>
  <% if @runners.each do |runner| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= runner.id %></td>
    <td><%= runner.name %></td>
    <td><%= runner.finish_time %></td>
    <td><%= (count += 1).ordinalize %></td>
   </tr>
    <% end.empty? %>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="4"> No Record Found</td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
```

but the above doesn't work if two or more users finished at exactly time.

This is the desired output:

[image]

Note that Eyal's position is `4th` (not `3rd`) because two participants came second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ilya has a good idea with grouping the results, but that solution won't skip 3rd place in the example. We need another variable to keep track of place.

```
<% count = 1 %>
<% @runners.group_by(&:finish_time).each do |(time, runners)| %>
  <% place = count %>
  <% runners.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= r.id %></td>
      <td><%= r.name %></td>
      <td><%= time %></td>
      <td><%= place.ordinalize %></td>
    </tr>
    <% count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: did you mean '@runners.each'  instead of runners.each at line 4? I tried '@runners.each' and it skipped the positions nicely (Thanks!), but it  executed a double loop, so I have repetition - 8 rows instead of 4 rows. I edited my question to add the table rows as that may have affected your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: I think I wasn't using the activerecord `group` method correctly. I've taken the results and grouped them with group_by instead - that should work now with `runners` (not `@runners`)

Comment: Nice. That worked, woulda taken a while to figure this out myself. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<% count = 0 %>
<% @runners.each do |runner| %>
  <td>runner.id</td>
  <td>runner.name</td>
  <td>runner.finish_time</td>
  <% if runner.finish_time == @runners[count].finish_time %>
    <td><%= count.ordinalize %></td>
    <% count += 1 %>
  <% else %>
     <td><%= (count += 1).ordinalize %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Since count is initialised to 0, <%= count.ordinalize %> prints 0th for the first run, attempt to change initialisation to 1 altered the if the condition.